# How to append div tag into a SVG rect element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg

I couldn't find a correct solution for this problem so I decided to write a new question.

I'm not even sure that this is possible but I hope it is.

So here is my HTML that the browser provides. I'm copying it from the "Elements" tab in the browser.

```
<svg width="960" height="728" style="margin-left: 0px;">
<g transform="translate(0,24)" style="shape-rendering: crispEdges;">
    <g class="depth">
        <g>
            <g>
                <rect class="child" x="0" y="0" width="960" height="704" style="fill: rgb(192, 192, 192);">1.1.1.
                    <div class="jstree">
                        <div>TestContent</div>
                    </div>
                </rect>
            </g>
        </g>
    </g>
</g>
```

(I'm creating everything with JS).

My problem is that I'm creating this div inside the rect tag, but this div and its content doesn't appear on the screen inside the rectangle.

I want to know if it is possible to make it appear and if it is how ?

Comment: The answer is simple: you *can't*! an SVG rect element cannot have a div (or any other HTML element) as a child. This is a doc I wrote for D3 (not your case), but that covers exactly your problem, have a look: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/d3.js/2537/core-svg-concepts-used-in-d3-js-visualization/17339/correctly-appending-an-svg-element#t=201609020833108633813  This example talks about appending SVG elements to other SVG elements incorrectly, and the same applies for appending HTML elements to SVG elements.

Comment: ditto to @GerardoFurtado's comment, and to add HTML elements in your svg, you need to use a `<foreignObject>` element.

Comment: Kaiido's tip is correct, but have in mind that IE doesn't support `foreignObject`...

Comment: Can you write me an answer with simple example of foreignObject which is working with my code ?

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, it's not possible: you *cannot* append an HTML element to an SVG element.

The only way for using a `div` (or a `p`, `h1`, `li` etc) in an SVG is by using `foreignObject`. In your code, something like this:

```html
<svg width="960" height="728" style="margin-left: 0px;">
<g transform="translate(0,24)" style="shape-rendering: crispEdges;">
    <g class="depth">
        <g>
            <g>
                <rect class="child" x="0" y="0" width="960" height="704" style="fill: rgb(192, 192, 192);">
                </rect>
                <foreignObject x="100" y="100" width="100" height="100">
      <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class="jstree">
                        <div>TestContent</div>
                    </div>
         </foreignObject>
            </g>
        </g>
    </g>
</g>
```

Notice that `foreignObject` comes *after* the rectangle, not inside it (as in your code). Also, notice that `foreignObject` does not work in IE: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/SVG/Element/foreignObject

Comment: is there any solution that is also IE friendly?